# Changing product logo URL in google oauth consent screen after verification process is not allowed

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

Our app underwent the google review process recently. We received a confirmation that the app has been approved and if we need to change it we'll have to undergo the review process again.

We tried to change the product logo URL after it was verified but in vain. It shows an error stating `You do not have permission to perform this action`. 
There is a link to update form which does not have the product logo URL field. (https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_update)

When we tried to contact google support, they responded saying it is not possible to change product logo now.[image]

Is there anyway to get our product logo changed in the Google OAuth consent screen?

Comment: Did you get a response from google about the issue? We have the same issue with the product logo URL right after the google review process. It is a surprise to me that they did override the original settings of the oauth consent screen, without the possibility to fill in or edit the product logo URL field.

Comment: @IoannisTzikas : They said they don't have a clear date for changing the product logo URL and they'll be making the changes throughout the rest of the year. We still don't have a product logo URL.